# Android Gradle Plugin - what should I use in place of incubating abstractions, such as defaultConfig?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am new to Gradle, and I'm trying to port my android groovy build script to kts.

I have a working build, however Android studio is complaining (all over the place) about my syntax.

For example:

> defaultConfig: 'defaultConfig(kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<? super
> com.android.build.api.dsl.ApplicationDefaultConfig,kotlin.Unit>)' is
> marked unstable with @Incubating

> 'setApplicationId(java.lang.String)' is declared in unstable 'com.android.build.api.dsl.ApplicationBaseFlavor' marked with @Incubating

this goes on & on.  When I look at the documentation, I can see that it is incubating, but it doesn't say what to replace with it, etc.

```
android {
    compileSdk = 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "myappId"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 31
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Should I just ignore these warnings?  If so why are they warnings?

---

I just opened the project, on another machine and do not see the warning.  The machine is running the exact same version of Android Studio:

- JVM
- Kotlin
- Gradle

When i click on something like the defaultConfig and navigate to the source, i see that it comes from exact same module.  And it is marked as @Incubating.

I also checked the settings>Editor>Inspections and they both have the same settings.

Answer (score 1):

This warning is nothing to do with Android Studio or compiler.
It's from Gradle build system: [link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Incubating.html)

The meaning of the warning is following:

> ...the feature is currently a work-in-progress and may change at any time.

For my pet-projects I do `@Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")` to dismiss it.
But I would **strongly recommend** you **not doing this** for commercial/production projects. Better approach is to wait till the feature is stabilized by Gradle developers if you are using latest stable version. Or update to latest stable if possible.

Comment: However, it seems like everything is incubating forever and no ‘stable’ alternative in sight. Even the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#supported_features) propose these.